# Orbot as a middle relay - does it make any sense?

Tags: relays, orbot, network-health

Orbot can be set to run as a non-exit relay
[image: Options from the setting screen]

However IIRC it take a little while (weeks) before non-exit relays become trusted enough to route real world traffic through them.

Given that the IP address of my phone changes relatively frequently does it make sense to donate some of my "all you can eat" data allowance to the network, or am I needlessly slowing my phone down?

Answer (score 1):

Using your phone as a relay will take up some of your phones computing power but what I'd be worried about is mainly the bandwitdth, if you lose connection to wifi you will use up data quickly. Along with using WiFi you will stand out if you are on a public WiFi and probably not a good idea I'm home wifi.

All in all it isn't worth it

Comment: my query is more about the time it take's middle relay's to start accepting "real" traffic and the relatively rapidly changing IP address on mobile networks.
My mobile contract allows for unlimited data so that not so much of an issue.